# How to set the sampling probobility of the opentelemetry agent?

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-java

I am using open telemetry java agent to instrument an application. Basically just set the location of the agent in the VM options.
I am trying to change the sampling probability.

Tried -Dota.trace.sampling.probability=0, but it still have trace_ids coming out to the backend.